# Is it possible to have ListView inside a dialog?

Tags: android, listview, dialog

Basically, I have this LazyList which originally created by [Fedor][1] , I am just wondering if there is anyway to put it inside a dialog. Please help me, I've been struggling for days trying to figure this out, I really need your help. Thanks in advance!

Here his code when you need it:

```
    p

            list.setOnItemClickListener(new OnItemClickListener() {
            public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position,long id) {  



                    if(position == 0){



                        final Dialog dialog = new Dialog(MainPictures.this, R.style.CustomDialogTheme);
                        dialog.setContentView(R.layout.customlayout);
                        dialog.setTitle(null);
                        dialog.setCancelable(true);
                        dialog.show();
                        WindowManager.LayoutParams lp = dialog.getWindow().getAttributes(); 
                        lp.dimAmount=0.5f;  
                        dialog.getWindow().setAttributes(lp);  
                        dialog.getWindow().addFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_BLUR_BEHIND);



                    }




                    else {
                        System.out.println("Error");
                    }

                    }                                                                                                       
                });


        }






        private String[] mStrings={
                "http://www.urlurl/hi.png",
                "http://www.urlurl/hi.png",

        };
    }
```

Comment: you want "mStrings"  to be in listView..?

Comment: Yes, but like I said before it always gives me an error

Comment: Actually, this whole code is what I want to be in my dialog

Comment: @Lean then add this tag in xml under your activity tag "<activity android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Dialog">"

Comment: Take a look my code above, I simplyfy it a little bit.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

have a lokk at this.

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/dialogs.html

**Update:**

Another solution could be Create an ACtivity and Put listView in it and make its Theme as Dialog.

read this to know how to set theme http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/themes.html

Comment: I know how to create a basic dialog, but I don't know how to create a listview inside a dialog

Comment: @Lean.. you can add a list to Dialog, it looks just like ListView, scroll down and read whole documentation.

Comment: There is no listview there. Please help me

Comment: @Leon.. there is no listView but you can add a list of Strings to AlertDialog, which just looks like AlertDialog. See my edits for update..

Answer (score 0):

You have to create a dialog with a custom layout. So for example, use this layout

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
              android:id="@+id/layout_root"
              android:orientation="horizontal"
              android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="400dip"
              android:padding="10dp">
    <ListView android:id="@+id/MyAwesomeList"
               android:layout_width="fill_parent"
               android:layout_height="fill_parent"/>
</LinearLayout>
```

And use it for a dialog like this when you're creating the dialog in the onCreateDialog() callback of your Activity:

```
Context mContext = getApplicationContext();
Dialog dialog = new Dialog(mContext);

dialog.setContentView(R.layout.custom_dialog);
dialog.setTitle("Custom Dialog");

ListView myList = (ListView) dialog.findViewById(R.id.MyAwesomeList);
// set the list adapter and stuff
```

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it's kinda different when I used Fedor's ListView, it gives me this error "The constructor LazyAdapterWallpaper(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener(){}, String[]) is undefined"