# How to use StartActivityForResult()

Tags: android, android-fragments

In my app I need to ask the user a *quick* `input`.

**I need to get a result from this** *Flash-Activity* **and then get back to the previous one.**

I've read about the `StartActivityForResult()` method, but I'm not yet sure how to use it properly, any examples?

**EDIT:**

I've tried to pass the Player object via intent (as the result) using the method I used in all the app applied to this method of the StartActivityForResult():

In my second Activity (the one where I need to get the result from):

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
Player playerKilled = players.get(position);

Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
bundle.putSerializable("PLAYER_KILLED", (Serializable) playerKilled);
intent.putExtras(bundle);

setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

My Main Activity where I need to take the result to:

```
if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {

    Intent intent = this.getIntent();
    Bundle bundle = intent.getExtras();
    playerKilled = (Player)bundle.getSerializable("PLAYER_KILLED");

    Toast.makeText(this, playerKilled.getName() + "the " + playerKilled.getCardName() + " has died, and he/she had the ID: " + playerKilled.getId(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
```

Comment: Is there a problem here or are you asking for a design opinion on your own app? If the later, that's off topic for StackOverflow

Comment: Consider moving this question to the [code review](http://codereview.stackexchange.com/) site.

Comment: Nope, I'm asking how to make a sort of pop-up windows, I mean, an activity that dosen't make loose the focus on tha main activity (the ListView). The code is just to help you. If you need to take a closer look, not asking for a review. @MrD

Comment: Yeah it's @cricket_007 How to make such.. "activity"

Comment: @Snip3r_bow Might want to rephrase the question in that case

Comment: Is a dialog suitable? Or else you could launch an activity that looks like a dialog?

Comment: Why not then simply create a simple dialog that you show within that same activity?

Comment: Would that fit a ListView right? @Eenvincible

Comment: @Snip3r_bow I'm not sure what you're asking exactly. Do you want the input to be from the dialog, because you mentioned that you don't want it to lose focus from the main activity? What do you mean by this - do you want to still be able to access the activity's `ListView` (as you mentioned) whilst you are asking for an input?

Comment: I'm sorry, I still didn't know the StartActivityForResult() method when I first asked this question, now I know it my question is how to properly use it to start another Activity and get back a result from it (the name of a Player object inside our RecyclerView). I just need to know how to use this method, I know how to get what I want, but I don't know how to send it using this method @FarbodSalamat-Zadeh

Comment: @Snip3r_bow So I assume you want the main activity to launch a second activity with the `RecyclerView` (from your previous question) and then when an item is clicked, it returns the result to the main activity.

Comment: Right to the point ;) @FarbodSalamat-Zadeh

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You can request user input in a number of ways, but if you want to use a new `Activity`, as you mentioned, we can use `startActivityForResult()` to launch a new activity and return the input from there.

Firstly, I would highly recommend reading through [this Stack Overflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10407371/4230345) about how to use `startActivityForResult()`. I will explain how you can implement it for your specific use case.

So, you need to understand that `startActivityForResult()` has two parameters:

- the `Intent` (which you use to pass data between activities)
- a "request code" integer that identifies your request

It is good practice to use a constant for your request code that you can access in both of your activities. For example, in your main activity, you could add:

```
public static final int REQUEST_CODE = 1;
```

This would be accessible in both activities since it is `public`, and it would work for a request code since it is an `int` (integer).

In your main activity, you need an action (such as a button press) to start your second activity. Let's assume it is a button click that triggers this action:

```
Button button = (Button) findViewById(R.id.your_button);
button.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        // actions that will happen when the button is pressed:

        Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
        startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
    }
});
```

Basically, we are creating an `Intent` which specifies our current activity (`this`) and the second activity. We use the intent in the `startActivityForResult()` method along with the `REQUEST_CODE` we declared earlier.

Now, in our second activity, we need something to trigger the data being returned back. From [the previous question you asked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37786796/how-to-display-an-arraylist-in-a-recyclerview), I'm assuming you want data to be returned to the main activity when a `RecyclerView` item has been clicked. Here is [part of my answer to that question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37787525/4230345) modified to show how data will be sent back.

```
ExampleClickAdapter clickAdapter = new ExampleClickAdapter(yourObjects);
clickAdapter.setOnEntryClickListener(new ExampleClickAdapter.OnEntryClickListener() {
    @Override
    public void onEntryClick(View view, int position) {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("pos", position);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    }
});
recyclerView.setAdapter(clickAdapter);
```

The above will send back the position of the list item from the `RecyclerView` clicked.

Have a look at the `Intent`'s `putExtra()` method. This is what passes data. You can see that I have passed a String `"pos"` and the variable for the item `position` in this method, but why:

```
intent.putExtra("key", object);
```

The `putExtra` method of `Intent`s always use a String key and another object, such as your integer variable, `position`. The key will be used again when retrieving this object (as I will show you later).

We use `Activity.RESULT_OK` to say that we are passing a result, but you can use `Activity.RESULT_CANCELED` if you don't want to send back a result - this is explained in the answer link I mentioned at the beginning. Note that if you use `Activity.RESULT_CANCELED`, you would not need to use `putExtra` as there would be nothing to send back.

Finally, you need to add something into your main activity which will deal with receiving the results from your second activity:

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {

    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE) {

        if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_OK) {
            int result = data.getIntExtra("pos");
            // do something with the result

        } else if (resultCode == Activity.RESULT_CANCELED) {
            // some stuff that will happen if there's no result
        }
    }
}
```

We use the `onActivityResult` method for this.

At the beginning of this method, we are checking to see if the `requestCode` is the same as the one we defined earlier (as a public constant, `REQUEST_CODE`).

If so, we continue and check to see what the `resultCode` of the result was. If data was sent back (`Activity.RESULT_OK`), we can retrieve it using `getIntExtra()` as the `position` was an integer (similarly, use `getStringExtra()` if you are returning a String). Then you can do something with the returned data. However, if data was not sent back (as we mentioned earlier with `Activity.RESULT_CANCELED`), you can do something else.

Hopefully this helps you with implementing your idea, but a Google search would've found the answer I mentioned above ([here is the link again](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10407371/4230345)) which clearly explained how to use  `startActivityForResult()`. Other answers for this question also explain it well, but perhaps you needed guidance on how to implement it in your use case (i.e. combined with your code from the previous question you had), which is why I've provided the explanation above.

You can also read the [Android documentation on *Getting a Result from an Activity*](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) as well as Android documentation for the [`startActivityForResult()` method](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#startActivityForResult(android.content.Intent, int)) and [`Intent`s](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent.html).

Comment: Hey, I'd like to pass as value the Player object, but my method (which I've updated my question with) doesn't seem to be working, any ideas why?

Comment: @Snip3r_bow To pass objects, I would make your `Player` object implement `Parcelable` instead of using `Serializable`. There's a good answer explaining how to do that [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/7181792/4230345). After modifying your `Player` object in this way, I would use `putParcelable("PLAYER_KILLED", playerKilled)` - you should not have to cast it to anything here. Similarly, in your main activity, you would use `getParcelable` instead of `getSerializable`. There is the [official documentation for this](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/Parcelable.html) as well.

Comment: Cheers, I've temporary solved this passing the position and gettin' the Player in the `MainActivity`, but will surely try to implement the `Parcelable` in the future updates as I've heard it's better than `Serializable` in some cases

Comment: Hey man, may I ask you to have a look at [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37924789/passing-a-reference-in-java) question? I think you're one of the only ones who can really understand and help there

Comment: @Snip3r_bow I'll check it out tomorrow - is it your question?

Comment: Yeah, I'm sorry for that

Comment: Found anything? Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correctly, I am confident you want this solution:

```
startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
```

simply create your activity with a list of items (recyclerview?) then to start it in order to get the results back, you basically create your intent and call the above method.

```
Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(intent, SOME_UNIQUE_CODE);
```

Now, after you are in the list activity, simply do the following when a user has selected the item:

```
intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("id", "Some Value Here to return");
setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
finish();
```

So, immediately a user clicks an item from the list, you use this code to pass back your value and close this list activity.

Lastly, to actually receive this value passed, you simply Override `onActivityResult()`

```
@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data){
    if (requestCode == REQUEST_CODE){
        if (resultCode == RESULT_OK){

            id = data.getExtras().getString("id");
        }
    }
}
```

This is all you need! I would say creating an activity is totally fine even though it does just one thing - displays  a list of items! I hope this helps you! Good luck and happy coding!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do is pop up an activity that looks like a dialog.

In the manifest, where you declare the activity, include a dialog theme:

```
<activity
    android:name="com.myapp.DialogActivity"
    android:theme="@android:style/Theme.Holo.Light.Dialog"
    ...
</activity>
```

Then call the activity the normal way you would, with a result if you like:

```
Intent i = new Intent(this, DialogActivity.class);
startActivityForResult(i, REQUEST_CODE);
```

Comment: Mh, and would this dialog themed activity make me go back to the previous activity after closed?

Comment: I think it's right what I was asking for, reading the Official tutorial of the startActivityForResult method, will let you know if this worked

Comment: Yeah, it would bring you back to the previous activity that called it - I use this myself instead of the dialog classes when I need something a little more powerful.

Comment: Mh, I see on the docs I have to use the CursorLoader, is it right? Take a [look](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html)

Comment: It's in the last part of code (there are 3 in total)

Comment: That example is just how to root through the contact list on your phone. It depends what data you're trying to persist - I'm a fan of `SharedPreferences` for a lot of things. But you return to the activity in `onActivityResult` where you can process whatever you passed it from the dialog activity in another `intent`.

Comment: Alright, I think I got ya, I'll try now to apply that to my app, I'll let you know here if I was successful or not :)

Comment: Hey, how may I edit the layout? I mean, the one of the dialog

Comment: Like to make display a `ListView`

Comment: That's getting away from the scope of the question, but it's an activity - so you'd set it up in the normal fashion as any other ListView.

Comment: Mmmm you're right, as it doesn't work shall I make a question on this?

Comment: Sure, I'll check it out. But you should be able to customize the activity class as needed.

Comment: I'm not crazy, check out here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7631007/is-it-possible-to-have-listview-inside-a-dialog

Comment: ie create an xml that includes a listview element, and put the xml in your setContentView in the DialogActivity's onCreate

Comment: But what's the main difference between creating a Dialog with a ListView inside and a ListAvticity?