# Change text in multi action buttons in Android

Tags: android, button, android-activity

I have an Android application where if the user creates an account, they click on the "create an account" button, it takes them to a second activity (DriverDetailsActivity) to fill out a form.  Once the form is completed, the user will then click on the "UPDATE" button which will return them to the LoginActivity and the "Create an Account" text should change to "Register" but it is not working.

The code I am supplying isn't working.

[image]

**LoginActivity:**

```
final Button mRegisterButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.email_registration_button);
    mRegisterButton.setTag(1);
    mRegisterButton.setText("Create an Account");
    mRegisterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick (View v) {
            final int status = (Integer) v.getTag();
            if (status == 1) {
                Intent intent = new Intent(getBaseContext(), DriverDetailsActivity.class);
                startActivity(intent);
                mRegisterButton.setText("Register");
            }
        }
    });
```

**DriverDetailsActivity (2nd Activity)**

```
        // Once completed all fields, user is sent back to DriverLoginActivity
    update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {
            Intent intent = new Intent(DriverDetailsActivity.this, DriverLoginActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
        }
    });
```

How can I do this?

Comment: You are working in onCreate or onResume of LoginActivity ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of startActivity we have startActivityForResult(intent,requestCode)

This method is specially used when you want to go to an activity and get some result back.

use like this :

In activity A

```
startActivityForResult(intent,100);
```

In activity B when you complete your task what you do is

```
setResult(RESULT_OK);
finish();
```

In activity A you override this method:

```
    @Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
    if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
        //Do your work here
    }
}
```

Apparently you can setResult(RESULT_CANCELLED) also to notify that the result is not correct.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Just to clarify I am putting these in the right areas:
startActivityForResult(intent, 100) is replacing startActivity(intent).  setResult(...) is before Intent intent ...??

Comment: Yes. The 100 is actually is a request code which can be changed to any value. Then in onActivityResult we match this if it is from the same request code that we sent.

Comment: Activity A
final Button mRegisterButton = (Button)findViewById(R.id.email_registration_button);
mRegisterButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
@Override
public void onClick (View v) {
Intent intent = new Intent(DriverLoginActivity.this, DriverDetailsActivity.class);
                startActivityForResult(intent,100);
            }
        });
then outside of onCreate is the Override function

Comment: Perfect.!! Happy coding.

Comment: Its still not working, I must be doing something wrong

Comment: Activity B:
update.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                setResult(RESULT_OK);
                finish();
                Intent intent = new Intent(DriverDetailsActivity.this, DriverLoginActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("BACK", "Register");
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });

Comment: No don't start the activity again. Remove the Intent intent from the activity b

Comment: OK, did that., but with Activity A: 
if (requestCode == 100 && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            //Do your work here
            mRegisterButton.setText("Register");
        }
setting the text seems to crash the app, how do I change the text, so I can implement the registration

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/148919/discussion-between-sarthak-gandhi-and-lizg).

Answer (score 0):

For this you can use  startActivityForResult() to get result from DriverDetailsActivity and update text in onActivityResult.

For more info check these links

https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html

[How to use StartActivityForResult()](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37768604/how-to-use-startactivityforresult)

Answer (score 0):

Try this

**LoginActivity:**

```
if( getIntent().getExtras() != null) {
            btnOne.setText(getIntent().getStringExtra("BACK"));
        }else{
            btnOne.setText("Create");
        }


        btnOne.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                if(btnOne.getText().toString().equalsIgnoreCase("Create")){
                    Intent intent = new Intent(MainActivity.this,SecondActivity.class);
                    startActivity(intent);
                }else{
                    //do registration
                }
            }
        });
```

**DriverDetailsActivity (2nd Activity)**

```
btnTwo.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                    Intent intent = new Intent(SecondActivity.this,MainActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("BACK","Register");
                    startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
```

Comment: Arnold Brown  This did not work.  Keeps giving me an error that application has stopped.  I put getIntent .. (LoginActivity) under setContentView in onCreate and it gave error.

Comment: All fixed. Tks anyway