# How to pass extras from an intent to onActivityResult() method?

Tags: android, android-intent

I'm trying to pass some data from an intent to `onActivityResult()` method, this is what I did:

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
intent.putExtra("STRING", some_data);
startActivityForResult(intent, 1);
```

then:

```
@Override
public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: " + data.getStringExtra("STRING"));
    // or
    Log.d(TAG, "onActivityResult: " + data.getExtras().getString("STRING"));

}
```

but this keeps giving me a NullPointerException `(data == null)`, did I miss something?

Comment: The `data` `Intent` in `onActivityResult()` is *not* the `Intent` that you used with `startActivityForResult()`. Instead, it is the `Intent` used by `setResult()` of the activity that was started, to send back a result.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let's say you start `Activity` B from `Activity` A using `startActivityForResult(intent, 1);`

The data you pass in this intent is available in `Activity` B.

If you want to pass some data back from `Activity` B to `Activity` A, you have to call `setResult()` before calling `finish()` in the Activity B. Like this:

```
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putExtra("STRING", some_data);
        setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
```

Refer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37857660/4586742) for more info.

Answer (score 0):

You can call

```
setResult(int resultCode, Intent data)
```

before call finish() method of your second activity.

[https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult(int, android.content.Intent)](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/app/Activity.html#setResult(int,%20android.content.Intent))