# How to close custom dialog which itself is an activity and get data from it?

Tags: android, android-dialog, customdialog, cancel-button

I have created custom dialog and I want to close it on **Cancel** button click. I searched on google, most of the people are using **Dialog** or **AlertDialog** but I am not using anything like that. This is my `TextDialogActivity` which is loading on button click in my app. From `MainActivity` I am just rendering another activity as custom dialog. When I click `Save` button on the dialog I want to access data in parent activity, which is stored in a variable `textData` in child activity.

```
  public class TextDialogActivity extends AppCompatActivity {
  TabHost tabHost;
  private static final int FILE_SELECT_CODE = 0;
  private String textData;

  private Button browse;
  private Button cancel_button1;
  private Button cancel_button2;
  private TextView text_preview;

  @Override
  protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
      super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
      setContentView(R.layout.text_dialog_layout);

      browse = findViewById(R.id.browse_file_button);
      text_preview = findViewById(R.id.text_preview);
      cancel_button1 = findViewById(R.id.cancel_button);
      cancel_button2 = findViewById(R.id.cancel_button2);

      tabHost = findViewById(R.id.tabHost);
      tabHost.setup();

      TabHost.TabSpec spec=tabHost.newTabSpec("tag1");

      spec.setContent(R.id.encode_dialog_text_tab);
      spec.setIndicator("Edit Text");
      tabHost.addTab(spec);

      spec=tabHost.newTabSpec("tag2");
      spec.setContent(R.id.encode_dialog_browse_tab);
      spec.setIndicator("Browse");
      tabHost.addTab(spec);

      browse.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
              showFileChooser();
          }
      });

      cancel_button1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
                // close dialog
          }
      });

      cancel_button2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
          @Override
          public void onClick(View v) {
                 // close dialog
          }
      });

   }
 }
```

I added `@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog` to my **AndroidManifest.xml** to make my dialog.

```
 <activity
        android:name=".activity.TextDialogActivity"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.AppCompat.Dialog"
        android:label="Secret Message">
 </activity>
```

This is the screenshot.
[image]

Comment: Can you make it clear if you are displaying a dialog then when you want to dismiss the dialog?

Comment: @Jai Prak If I understood correctly you want to open a popup (which is an activity), from a parent activity, and access data from parent activity in the popup? If this is the case you will have to use intent.

Comment: Instead of Activity you can create a dialog which extends Dailog and there you can do your stuff...and you can access dismiss method in that dialog

Comment: @Kemo yeah same. But I want to access data from the popup to parent activity.

Comment: After adding your screenshot....just change your AppCompactActivity to Dialog...and use 'dismiss' method

Comment: Create a constructor and pass the data from constructor..

Comment: @JaiPrak I think that this is the best solution, I did the same thing.

Comment: Creating an activity is not the best way for diaog

Answer (score -1, accepted):

My custom dialog/popup is an **activity** itself. I am not using Dialog or AlertDialog. For closing this dialog on Cancel button click, this is what I did:

```
 cancel_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            finish();  // Call this method to close the dialog
        }
 });
```

And for accessing data from child activity(`TextDialogActivity`) to parent(`MainActivity`) activity, I did the same as @Kemo suggested here in answers. This is the code:

```
// From Parent activity(MainActivity) opening popup on button click
popUpButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(getContext(), TextDialogActivity.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent, TEXTFILE);
        }
});

// From Child activity(TextDialogActivity) sending data to parent activity
save_button.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            if(!secretText.isEmpty()) {
              Intent intent = new Intent();
              intent.putExtra("popup_data", secretText);
              setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
              finish();
            }
        }
});
```

Now I want the result from child activity to parent activity for that I did this in `onActivityResult` method:

```
// In parent activity get data on onActivityResult
if (requestCode == TEXTFILE && resultCode == getActivity().RESULT_OK){
     secretText = data.getExtras().getString("popup_data", "");
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You should treat this as any other activity. Just use intent to send your data from popup activity to parent activity.

You should use the `data` `Intent` in `onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)` like this in the popup:

```
saveButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View view) {

        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.putStringArrayListExtra("popup_data", data);
        setResult(RESULT_OK, intent);
        finish();
    }
});
```

And in parent:

```
if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) { 
    ArrayList<String> popup_data= 
    data.getExtras().getStringArrayList("popup_data");
}
```

Comment: I want to access data from the popup to parent activity, not parent to popup.

Comment: It is very similar. Use intent to send your data from popup to parent activity, then in the parent activity use the onActivityResult: `public void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) `

Comment: @JaiPrak Glad it helped :)

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above, Activity is not the best to do that.

But just start your Dialog as an Activity for result.

Then when the user presses a button return the result and finish the Activity.

Then in the main Activity you get the result in `onActivityResult`

See an [example here](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result.html) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/37857660/1827254)

**Start the Activity (in MainActivity)**

> ```
>  Intent intent = new Intent(this, SecondActivity.class);
>         startActivityForResult(intent, REQUEST_CODE);
> ```

**Set the result (in the Dialog)**

> ```
> ExampleClickAdapter clickAdapter = new ExampleClickAdapter(yourObjects);
> clickAdapter.setOnEntryClickListener(new ExampleClickAdapter.OnEntryClickListener() {
>     @Override
>     public void onEntryClick(View view, int position) {
>         Intent intent = new Intent();
>         intent.putExtra("pos", position);
>         setResult(Activity.RESULT_OK, intent);
>         finish();
>     }
> });
> ```

**Receive the result (in MainActivity)**

> ```
> @Override
> protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
>     // Check which request we're responding to
>     if (requestCode == PICK_CONTACT_REQUEST) {
>         // Make sure the request was successful
>         if (resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
>             // The user picked a contact.
>             // The Intent's data Uri identifies which contact was selected.
>
>             // Do something with the contact here (bigger example below)
>         }
>     }
> }
> ```