# Null-Pointer Exception when trying to access an EditText from another activity in Kotlin

Tags: android, kotlin, nullpointerexception

EDIT : Solved by using `startActivityForResult()`

in Kotlin I am trying to set the content of an EditText of my main activity from within the HandleResult method of a barcode scanning activity, and I get a NPE. I have read https://kotlinlang.org/docs/tutorials/android-plugin.html

This is the barcode scanning activity

```
import kotlinx.android.synthetic.main.activity_main.*

...

override fun handleResult(rawResult: Result) {
    Toast.makeText(this, "Contents = " + rawResult.text +
            ", Format = " + rawResult.barcodeFormat.toString(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()
    doAsync {
        val url = "https://www.amazon.com/s/field-keywords=${rawResult.text}"
        val dom = Jsoup.connect(url).get()
        val title = dom.select("h2[class^=a-size-medium]")
        onComplete {
            txt_keyword.setText(title[0].text()) // <--- NPE crash
            onBackPressed()
        }
    }
```

The crash I get is

```
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'void android.widget.EditText.setText(java.lang.CharSequence)' on a null object reference
    at <mypackagename>.ScanActivity$handleResult$1$1.invoke(ScanActivity.kt:56)
    at <mypackagename>.ScanActivity$handleResult$1$1.invoke(ScanActivity.kt:20)
    at org.jetbrains.anko.AsyncKt$onComplete$1.run(Async.kt:57)
    at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:789)
    at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:98)
    at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
    at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6940)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
    at com.android.internal.os.Zygote$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(Zygote.java:327)
    at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:1374)
```

When **Ctrl+Entering** on **"txt_keyword"**, I do jump to the relevant part of the activity_main.xml!

Comment: when does this `handleResult()` method gets called ? to avoid crash, you can put null safety operator.

Comment: Don't try to access Views in one Activity from another Activity. Use an Intent to pass the data ( e.g using startActivity() ) or write the data to storage and retrieve it once the Activity with the View is in the foreground again

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In android, you should not access the content of an activity from another activity, what you should do is have the handleResult() method in the main activity and use [startActivityForResult()](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/intents/result) to start the Bar code activity then handle the result from the main activity or you could pass the content of the Edit Text from the from the main activity to the Bar Code activity through an [Intent with a Bundle](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/content/Intent) then handle the result in the BarCode activity.

Comment: A million times thank you! Thanks to the links you provided and https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37768604/how-to-use-startactivityforresult I now get the expected result using startActivityForResult. Thank you!