# Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context error

Tags: android, geolocation, location

I am building an app using location api, when a user click on a button, I want to get directions on the current activity so that I can proceed to tasks.
Here's the error I am getting.
Calling `startActivity()` from outside of an Activity  context requires the
`FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` flag. Is this really what you want?

I understand we can use `addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK` to get around the error. BUT the issue is I only want results from that intent to be displayed on the current activity.

Sample code. button click

```
   public void getDirections() {
        if (mState.getOrder() != null) {
            Uri gmmIntentUri;
            if (Order.PICKING_UP.equals(mState.getOrder().status)) {
                gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q="
                        + mState.getOrder().pickup.latitude + "," + mState.getOrder().pickup.longitude);
            } else {
                gmmIntentUri = Uri.parse("google.navigation:q="
                        + mState.getOrder().dropoff.latitude + "," + mState.getOrder().dropoff.longitude);
            }
            Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
            mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
            //mapIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // done to resolve Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context issue
            mContext.startActivity(mapIntent);
        }
    }
```

```
// context 
mContext = context.getApplicationContext() == null ? context : context.getApplicationContext();
```

Comment: Check this.. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37768604/how-to-use-startactivityforresult

Answer (score 0):

If you want to get data from Intent object you should method startActivityForResult.

```
      Intent mapIntent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_VIEW, gmmIntentUri);
        mapIntent.setPackage("com.google.android.apps.maps");
        //mapIntent.addFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK); // done to resolve Calling startActivity() from outside of an Activity context issue
        mContext.startActivityForResult(mapIntent);
```