# How to clear Webview Cache from Another activity

Tags: android, android-activity, android-webview, android-storage, android-websettings

I have a fullscreen Webview in Activity A and I have a clear button on Activity B to clear the Webview cache. How can I call that Webview clear functionality from another activity?

Tried the below scenario but it crashed because Webview will be null while calling this function from Activity B

```
   public void clearCacheWeb()
    {

        mWebview.clearCache(true);
        mWebview.clearHistory();
        mWebview.clearFormData();
    }
```

Is there any hope for this?

Comment: have you try startActivityForResult   https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37768604/how-to-use-startactivityforresult

Answer (score 0):

In `ActivityA` register a `BroadcastReceiver` that has an `IntentFilter` listening for ACTION="clear-cache". In the `BroadcastReceiver` method `onReceive()` you can clear the cache in the `WebView`.

In `ActivityB`, to clear the cache, send a local broadcast `Intent` with ACTION="clear-cache".

Comment: How can I get that Webview object on the method onReceive() of BroadcastReceiver?

Comment: The `BroadcastReceiver` can be an inner class of `ActivityA` so you should have access to it directly.

Comment: Tried this but not triggering the sendBroadcast(new Intent("CLEAR_CACHE"))  from button click.

Comment: please edit your question and post the code that you've added.